# RefreshControl doesn’t work in one of tabs with code used in similar way in other tabs

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uirefreshcontrol

The app tab uses refresh button to update list which works fine. Trying to use "pull down to refresh" but it doesn’t work at all.

```
protocol StaffHistoryDelegate: class {
    func updateList()

}

class StaffHistoryController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityLoad: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    let myRefreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {
        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: " ")
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
        return refreshControl
    }()



 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        prepareSearch()

        delegateStaffHystory =  self

        do { try self.frc.performFetch() }
        catch {}

        tableView.refreshControl = myRefreshControl
    }


    @IBAction func btnRefreshPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        loadingShow(text: " ")
        delegateTabController?.loadStaffBill(completion: { (error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                loadingHide()
                if error != nil {
                    let alert = getAlert(title: error?.localizedDescription, message: nil)
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        })

    }

    @objc private func refresh(sender: UIRefreshControl) {
        updateList()
        tableView.reloadData()
        sender.endRefreshing()
    }
```

Unfortunately I'm not a coder and it's really hard for me to understand what to do. (I managed to implement "pull down to refresh" on 2 other tabs but this one is coded in the different way).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming 'updateList()' is the function where your data is being refreshed -

```
@objc private func refresh(sender: UIRefreshControl) {
    updateList()
    tableView.reloadData()
    sender.endRefreshing()
}
```

Check if tableView is reloading data before the function finishes computing.
Try adding the following line when data is being refreshed in the 'updateList' function.

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

If 'btnRefreshPressed' works, try this

```
@objc private func refresh(sender: UIRefreshControl) {
    self.btnRefreshPressed(UIBarButtonItem())
    sender.endRefreshing()
}
```

Comment: it's like this `code`extension StaffHistoryController: StaffHistoryDelegate {
    func updateList() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.activityLoad.stopAnimating()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}`code`

Comment: In updateList(), only a ActivityIndicator in being stopped and TableView is reloaded but the data sources remains the same, are you fetching or updating data?

Comment: I don't know. I'm not a coder at all, I'm just trying to fix the code by our former employee who passed away (( I thought the RefreshControl should do the same as the Refresh Button, but I guess I'm wrong.

Comment: So, what if it's fetching?

Comment: You need to update your array by fetching data again from your data source.

Comment: @АльошаЛиманский does 'btnRefreshPressed' function work?

Comment: @AshmitBhui yes, it works great. I guess the button code refers to another file (TabController.swift) and I don't understand how to connect RefreshControl to the button so that their actions were the same. I tried but it didn’t work.

Comment: @АльошаЛиманский Try the edit in the answer above, let us know if it works...